# Running a code on Texmaker for the first time

Tags: error-handling, latex, interaction, pdflatex, texmaker

I have just installed Texmaker to work with LaTeX and tried to run a simple code with a titel but it gives me this error. Is it an issue in the LaTeX instalation process, or in the Texmaker itself?

[image: Error screenshot]

```
Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Comment: texmaker is just an editor, you will have to install a tex distribution as well. You can choose between miktex and texlive. Personally, I would suggest texlive. You can get it from tug.org

Comment: (if you are just starting, I would use texstudio instead of texmaker. This is a fork with much more features)

Comment: but I already have miktex installed

Comment: Then you might need to set the paths in the texmaker preferences.